# Spring3.2 RequestMapping produces = "application/json" not written to HttpServletResponse.ContentType

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, content-type

I'm using Jetty8,the servletResponse implmentation of jetty is org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response,which has a default ContentType "text/html;UTF-8",

my request mapping method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post1", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public NodeConfig post1(@RequestBody NodeConfig config) {
    return config;
}
```

A `GSONHttpMessageConverter` will process the returned value `config`,

```
GSONHttpMessageConverter extends
        AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>
```

I see in `AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(xxx)`:

```
HttpHeaders headers = outputMessage.getHeaders();
//...
headers.setContentType(contentType);
```

the "application/json" was set to response.headers,but not response.contentType. check `ServletServerHttpResponse.writeHeaders(xxx)`:

```
if (this.servletResponse.getContentType() == null && this.headers.getContentType() != null) {
                this.servletResponse.setContentType(this.headers.getContentType().toString());
            }
```

becuase the default contentType in `servletResponse`,the real contentType in `this.headers` is not set to response.

Does anyone enconter this problem? any idea to set contentType to servletResponse? (I don't like to inject servletResponse to my bussiness method)

I add the following code to `AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(xx)`to get it around.

```
    if (contentType != null && (outputMessage instanceof ServletServerHttpResponse)) {
        ServletServerHttpResponse response = (ServletServerHttpResponse) outputMessage;
        response.getServletResponse().setContentType(contentType.toString());
   }
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use Jackson? It's as easy as adding it to your class path where it will then marshall your returning objects to JSON automagically.

Comment: My project is using GSON,and to write a messageConverter is not so hard